# JQuery add class to a link

Tags: php, jquery

My code is outputting a series of objects to the console, like:

- Object[a.mod-articles-category-title 362-o-que-e-o-bsc]
- Object[a.mod-articles-category-title curso-bs...e-gestao]
- Object[a.mod-articles-category-title curso-bs...processo]

The code looks like the following:

```
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($paginas); ?>;

$('a.mod-articles-category-title').each(function () {
    var links=$(this).attr('href');

    if(links.indexOf('/')!=-1){
        i=1;
    }
    else{
        i=0;
    }

    var procura=links.match(/(\d+)/g)[i];

    if(obj.indexOf(procura)!=-1){
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).addClass("visto");

    };

});
```

Where obj is an array returned by a PHP function and procura is returning a number with a link id.

If the number in procura is in the obj array, I want to add the class "visto", to give it a different style, but it isn't working...

Comment: To clarify, the jQuery objects are being shown in the console correctly but the class is not being added?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, the code is picking the right objects but not adding the class

Comment: I find that difficult to believe... Are you sure the css in the `visto` class isn't simply being overridden by a different style? Did you inspect the elements to see if the class was there?

Comment: Can you perform any other jQuery operations on the objects, like fading them out, or writing specific attributes to the console as an indicator?

Comment: Fade out is working, class "visto" isn't being added to the DOM.

Comment: Adding a class to an object, especially when you have a reference to it through `this`, is pretty foolproof. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/4fnJq/. I call shenanigans that `fadeOut` works, but `addClass` doesn't.

Comment: Your code makes sense. That's exactly what I want to do, but for some reason, the class 'visto' isn't being added to the elements. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I fixed the problem with $(this).css({"color":"red"});
It isn't perfect but it works...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I missed where you said that obj is an array. There's a slightly different check for that. Just check to see if `procura` is a valid index for the `obj` array, and check that `obj[procura]` exists.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxgLC/

<s>You're treating `obj` like a string, calling `indexOf` on it. If you are looking for a property on an object, use `hasOwnProperty`</s>

```
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(procura)){
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).addClass("visto");

};
```